# Build Element of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in loop

Tags: python, sage

So I was wondering (or don't understand the docs right) how to cast a string to be interpreted as Polynomial of a given ring.

So I know how to build the string in python for [given definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3siz.png) but I have no idea how to cast that to the polynomial ring

[image: Definition]

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you are looking for?  This is pretty vague.  Even a little code that gives a sense of what you have tried will help people help you.

Comment: @maxx You could also be more specific about what docs you are reading when you say (or I don't understand the docs right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I needed to unterstand the `ring.gens()` so that I can use them as variables

```
def build(alpha, beta, gamma):
    ring = PolynomialRing(GF(q, 'a'), 'x', 6)
    poly = alpha
    x = ring.gens()

    for j in range(0, self.v):
        for k in range(0, self.n):
            if j is k:
                poly += gamma[j, k] * x[j]
            else:
                poly += gamma[j, k] * x[j] * x[k]

    for k in range(0, self.n):
        poly += beta[k] * x[k]

    return poly
```